# Why do some cmd launched processes block/buffer output when the output is redirected?

Tags: windows, command-line, cmd, output-redirect

Why do some processes started at the command line on my **Windows** machine block/buffer their entire output if it is redirected and others not?

Example: `tracert` does not block/buffer output as it is written.  If one executes:

```
tracert ponyoverflow.com > output.txt
```

...the `output.txt` file grows over time.  This is completely how I would expect things to behave.

But, I'm trying to work with a potential vendor's software product ([iSpring SDK](http://www.ispringsolutions.com/products/ispring_sdk.html), if you must know) and it seems to buffer the complete output until the process has finished.  What I find confusing is that when this software is run at the command line the output comes piecemeal, line-by-line, as expected.

Why is there a difference in behavior between calling it with and without output redirection?

**Follow up miscellaneous questions:**

- Is this common and/or standard in the world of Windows command line programming?
- Is there anything I can do to grab the
- How do I communicate exactly, in Windows programmer parlance, to iSpring folks how I think their software should behave at the command line?

I'm not sure how important it is, but all this experimentation of mine is happening on a 64-bit Windows 7 Home Premium machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*(The folks at iSpring were much quicker responding to me requests than I could have dreamed.  Spot on.  Here is their answer to 'why' below.)*

Standard output in C++ is buffered by default.  The buffer size is about 4KB.  The buffer is flushed when the application finishes.  Data written to stdout are not buffered when standard output is connected with a console.

Comment: @StuThombson I currently have the same issue as you (not iSpring, though). Did you ever find a workaround? Is there a way of making the process flush immediately?